# How can I trigger a commit/save?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Users can be manipulated through form fields. But I can't figure out how I can save (commit) them. When ever I change the `lastName` of a `User` and click the save button I'll get the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: Attempted to handle event `save` on <App.User:ember309:1> while in state rootState.loaded.updated.uncommitted. Called with undefined
```

What do I have to change to save (commit) a record by clicking on the save button?

**index.html**

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="users">
  <table class='table'>
      {{#each model}}
        <tr>
          <td>{{view Ember.TextField valueBinding='lastName'}}</td>
          {{#with this as model}}
            <td><button {{bindAttr class=":btn isDirty:btn-primary:disabled"}} {{action "save" target="model"}}>save</button></td>
          {{/with}}
        </tr>
      {{/each}}
  </table>
</script>
```

**app.js**

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
  revision: 12,
  adapter: 'DS.FixtureAdapter'
})

App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('users', function() {
    this.resource('user', { path: ':user_id' })
  })
});

App.UsersRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return App.User.find();
  }
});

App.UserController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  save: function() {
    this.commit();    
  }  
})

App.User = DS.Model.extend({
  lastName: DS.attr('string')
})

App.User.FIXTURES = [{
  id: 1,
  lastName: "Smith"
}]
```

Comment: Is it maybe because you don't specify which record you want to save? `{{action save model}}`.

Comment: Which version (commit) of Ember-Data are you using? The `save` method on a `DS.Model` is available since [36d2e2a07](https://github.com/emberjs/data/commit/36d2e2a07a82cc67baab186c36c38c405186ac12#L1R292)

Comment: I just updated to the very latest data-ember version. No difference. I don't 100% understand the MVC structure for the client side yet. I guess it is a very basic mistake.

Comment: have you already tried replacing `{{action "save" target="model"}}` with `{{action save model}}` (and possibly adding `target="controller"`) as Gabor suggested?

Comment: `{{action save model}}` goes to the UsersController (which makes sense but because I don't have a save there it doesn't work). I tried `{{action save model target="UserController"}}` doesn't work at all. I need a version which goes to the UserController.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your code like this

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="users">
  <table class='table'>
      {{#each model in controller}}
        <tr>
          <td>{{view Ember.TextField valueBinding='lastName'}}</td>
          <td><button {{bindAttr class=":btn isDirty:btn-primary:disabled"}} {{action "save"}}>save</button></td>
        </tr>
      {{/each}}
  </table>
</script>
```

that uses `each model in controller` and not `#with this as model`

And you define then an `itemController`

```
App.UsersController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  itemController: 'user'
});
```

This will allow you to have the `save` method of the `UserController` called.

Finally, make sure you save your record:

```
App.UserController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  save: function() {
    this.get('content.transaction').commit();
  }
})
```